# Apache Virtual Host pointing to Zend Framework Module

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2, virtualhost

Is there a way to setup apache virtual host so that it root points to a zend framework module?

The address of this module is only a route and there is no physical folder on the server.

Default module:

```
www.myintranet.com
```

Another module address:

```
www.myintranet.com/mymodule/
```

"mymodule" is not a physical folder, just a route.

Comment: Would you specify Zend Framework 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I can see no reason why you would ever *WANT* to do that?  ZF2 uses routes to the particular modules which is one of the strengths.  By hiding your files outside of the document_root you also get additional security where people cannot try to exploit your php files directly to gain access to your system.  In addition to this if your application has multiple modules and there is an issue on one of the modules you can simply disable that module temporarily without having to deal with apache rewrite rules etc.

The direct answer to your question however is that yes you can point apache at your module directory, however you will need to change and update all of the current rewrite rules to deal with the index.php autoloader and PATH related variables.  This would be more work than actually learning routing.  Once you figure it out it makes your life a lot easier.

I posted an answer here: [ZF2 Routing as in ZF1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370788/zf2-routing-as-in-zf1/13216091#13216091)

ON ZF1 -> ZF2 routing as it seems to confuse many people and that router should hopefully get you on your way as I suspect that is the issue you're having...